# Reading metadata from FLAC files with Java

Tags: java, flac

I want my users to upload their flac files and be able to read their metadata. After reading what type of tagging system flac uses (vorbis comments, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) i am looking for a library that allows me to read and write vorbis comments in java.  I was wondering if this might work for flac, http://code.google.com/p/jvorbiscomment/ or just ogg.  Are there any other options that you know.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). It supports MP3, MP4, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC and WMA, and it has limited support for WAV and Real.